# No data inserted during start of Play application (using Play 2.4 and reactivemongo 11.11)

Tags: playframework-2.4, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

We're using Play Framework 2.4 with mongodb 2.6. But since we migrated reactivemongo from `0.11.10` to `0.11.11-play24`, something is wrong.

We're loading some data into mongodb during the start of the application. Everything looks fine, the application started, no errors occurred in the logs but **no data were inserted in database**.

Here is the code for the start of the application in `Global.scala` :

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
   Logger.info("creating object in database...")
   someProducts.foreach{ product =>
     ProductDB.insertOrUpdate(product._id, product)
   }
}
```

To inject reactivemongo, we decided to not use the `@Inject()` for the moment, so we're using `current.injector` instead (according to the [Reactivemongo documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html)).
NB : we totally removed every trace of ReactiveMongoPlugin since it's deprecated in `play-reactivemongo 0.11.11-play24`.

Here we define our model and we inject ReactiveMongo :

```
abstract class MongoDB[T: Format, ID: Format] {
   def collection: JSONCollection

   def insertOrUpdate( _id: ID, o: T) = collection.update(Json.obj("_id" -> _id), o, upsert = true)
}

object ProductDB extends MongoDB[Product, String] {
  override def collection = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi].db.collection("products")
}
```

In `application.conf`, ReactiveMongoModule is enabled with this line :
`play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"`

Logs of the app :

```
[debug] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] application - starting application, build at: 2016-05-17T13:00:18+0200
[info] application - creating object in database...
[info] application - ReactiveMongoApi starting...
[info] application - ReactiveMongoApi successfully configured with DB 'application'! Servers:
[localhost:27017]
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
```

And here is the logs from mongodb :

```
2016-05-17T13:00:27.774+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65478 #3 (1 connection now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.833+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.833+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.880+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65479 #4 (2 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.880+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65480 #5 (3 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.880+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65481 #6 (4 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.880+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65482 #7 (5 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.880+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65483 #8 (6 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.881+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65484 #9 (7 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.881+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65485 #10 (8 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.881+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65486 #11 (9 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.882+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:65487 #12 (10 connections now open)
2016-05-17T13:00:27.888+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.888+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.888+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.889+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.890+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.890+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.890+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.890+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.891+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.891+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
2016-05-17T13:00:27.891+0200 [conn3] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
2016-05-17T13:00:27.891+0200 [conn3] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:178 0ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plug in after the database has been loaded:

```
    def db: DefaultDB = Await.result(reactiveMongoApi.database, Duration.Inf)
```

The thing is that now, `reactiveMongoApi.db` is synchronous and, if used directly, the connection is not done yet (lifecycle).

So I suggest that either you wait for the database (like code above)  or your just register callbacks into a Buffer which will be executed when the database has neem initialized

```
    reactiveMongoApi.database.onSuccess {
      case _ => callbacks.foreach(_())
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was exactly thinking for something like your first solution !